# Injection into generic parametrized property in Spring

Tags: spring, generics, dependency-injection, autowired

What is the best workaround for injection into generic parametrized property?

Simple example from [record in Spring Jira](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-5561):

```
@Component
public abstract class AbstractFoo<V extends Bar> {

   @Autowired
   protected V bar;
}

@Component
public ConcreteFoo1 extends AbstractFoo<ConcreteBar1> {
}

@Component
public ConcreteFoo2 extends AbstractFoo<ConcreteBar2> {
}
```

When I have such abstract `AbstractFoo` class and try to determine Spring bean which should be injected through generecis (`ConcreteFoo1`, `ConcreteFoo1`) Spring throws exception such as:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'foo.ConcreteFoo1'
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: 
No unique bean of type [bar.Bar] is defined: 
expected single matching bean but found 2: [concreteBar1, concreteBar2]
```

I tested similar scenarion in Spring 3.2.1. 
What is the best workaround for this problem?

This problem was reported at 10/Mar/09.
Why is this functionality still not implemented in Spring? Are there any complications preventing from solving this insufficiency?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is like if you wrote:

```
  @Autowired
  protected Bar bar;
```

Spring just can't understand that you want to inject ConcreteBar1

So, you can use setter injection:

```
public abstract class AbstractFoo<V extends Bar> {
    protected V bar;
} 

@Component
public class ConcreteFoo1 extends AbstractFoo<ConcreteBar1>{

@Inject
private void setBar(ConcreteBar1 bar){
    this.bar = bar;
}
}
```